# Find a Unique Bounded Linear Mapping in the Hilbert Space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, riesz-representation-theorem

this is a question on Banach Spaces that I have encountered. I am new to this type of stuff, and despite doing many exercise questions, I am still unsure where to begin.

> Let $T\colon H\mapsto H$ be a bound linear operator on a Hilbert Space H. Meaning T is linear and satisfies the relation $||Tg||\le K||g|| \forall g\in H$ Show there exist a unique bounded mapping $T^*\colon H\mapsto H \ni (Tf,g)=(f,T^*g)\forall f,g\in H$.

If I'm not mistaken, $T^*$ is an adjoint of T. 
Since we're working with Hilbert Spaces, I'm thinking of applying one of the three Riesz Representation Theorems, perhaps the first one.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f \to \langle Tf, g \rangle$ is a continuous linear map so (by Riesz Theorem) there exists an element $T^{*}g$ such that $f \to \langle Tf, g \rangle =\langle f, T^{*}g \rangle$. Linearilty of $T^{*}$ is easy to verify. Note that $|\langle f, T^{*}g \rangle |=| \langle Tf, g \rangle|\leq ||Tf|| \, ||g||\leq ||T||\, ||f||\, ||g||$. Taking sup over $f$ we get $||T^{*}g|| \leq ||T|| \, ||g||$ so $T^{*}$ is bounded.

Comment: +1 You forgot "there exists a *unique* element $T^*g$".

Comment: Yes, I had left uniqueness and linearity both left to the OP.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to prove that $T^*$ is linear, bounded, and continuous. Now I just have to try and prove uniqueness.

Comment: I followed the proof of one of the Riesz Representation Theorems, which I was able to prove that $T^*g$ is unique.